# No reputation for accept and upvote

Tags: bug, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Something seems to have gone wrong in calculation my reputation.

According to [what is reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), the daily limit is 200.

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. **Bounty awards, accepted answers**, and association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

According the [reputation section](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542723/ferrybig?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2016-01-28%2018:26:41Z) on my profile, I didn't get reputation for a **accept** and 2 upvotes.

[image: The reputation section on my profile]

I got 8 upvotes and 1 downvote today, were 1 upvote and 0 downvotes are on removed posts. 7 of those upvotes actually gave me reputation.

I got 3 answer accepts today, but only 2 answer accepts gave me reputation. According to the reputation page, this has no limits.

Outside the fact that I didn't get the reputation, I got the [mortarboard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard?userid=1542723) badge.

My [/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) shows:

```
....
 2  34995382 (10)
 1  35057533 (15)
 2  35057533 (10)
 2  35057533 (10)
 2  35063596 (10)
 1  35063596 (15)
 2  35065446 (10)
 2  34995382 (10)
 9  35062001 (100)
 3  35065446 (-2)
 2  35065446 (10)
-- 2016-01-28 rep +198  = 1569      

** rep today: 198

....

earned at least 200 reputation on 0 days
```

Even if it was the reputation limit, shouldn't my rep reach 200 according to the reputation url?

**My question is: Why didn't I get reputation for the accept, even through I never reached 200 rep?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You had made the answer a community wiki when you posted it, which means you don't gain reputation from the answer. I've removed the wiki status from it since there's no real reason for it to be there. Your reputation will recalculate itself shortly.

Comment: Oops, facepalm. Can there be a indication in the reputation section to reflect this?