# Reputation points for the day locked below 300

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

Yesterday my reputation points reached 291 after which there were two upvotes on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40917250/2592042) meaning a additional 20 reputation points should have been added to my total reputation points, making it 311 (and total of 35 from this answer alone).

But that didn't happen (final reputation points shows only 15 from this answer). **Is there a maximum reputation limit for a day?**

Also, I looked into these two posts *[No reputation for accept and upvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315676/no-reputation-for-accept-and-upvote)* and *[question shown upvoted but reputation is not added!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283087/i-didnt-get-200-rep-for-the-day-but-still-question-shown-upvoted-but-reputation)* which pointed out either the question or the answer was marked as community wiki and hence such behaviour, but in my case neither the question nor the answer is marked as such. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Congratulations on your Mortarboard badge…

Comment: @deceze now I understand the `cap` meaning.. thanks